JDK23 and pinning threads on synchronized blocks
I am trying to confirm if jdk23 (to be released next week) has already the capability to not pin threads on synchronized blocks.
Checking this JEP draft: Adapt Object Monitors for Virtual Threads seems the work is done, but expecting: "The changes proposed depend upon a specification change to the JVM TI function GetObjectMonitorUsage in JDK 23", which resolution is approved.
Can anyone confirm? Thanks.

No, not included in Java 23.
JEP draft: Adapt Object Monitors for Virtual Threads has a status of submitted.
A “submitted” JEP is only the third of six stages in its maturity. By definition the work cannot be completed for inclusion in an OpenJDK release.

• Draft --- In circulation by the author for initial review and consensus-building
• Posted --- Entered into the JEP Archive by the author for wider review
• Submitted --- Declared by the author to be ready for evaluation
• Candidate --- Accepted for inclusion in the Roadmap by the OpenJDK Lead
• Funded --- Judged by a Group or Area Lead to be fully funded
• Completed --- Finished and delivered

See JEP 1 for definitions and details about how JEPs work.

Yes, the JEP is submitted (renamed since you posted this answer).
There are also Early Access (EA) builds with the changes at: https://jdk.java.net/loom/

@AlanBateman Shouldn’t this older JEP have “Relates to” links at the top, taking us to the newer JEP? (And, thank you so much for all your terrific work!)
